# Help for the URL easter egg in the book 'Ready Player One'

Tags: ready-player-one

I already know the URL itself. I want to know which pages contain the typos that make up the URL for the Easter egg in the book *Ready Player One*.

Comment: It's not one page. It's a whole load of intentional typos throughout the book that make up the URL.

Answer (score 7):

> Scattered throughout the text of *Almanac* were a series of marked letters. Each of these letters had a tiny, nearly invisible "notch" cut into its outline. I'd first noticed these notches the year after Halliday died. I was reading my hard copy of the *Almanac* at the time, and so at first I thought the notches were nothing but tiny printing imperfections, perhaps due to the paper or the ancient printer I'd use to print out the *Almanac*. But when I checked the electronic version of the book available on Halliaday's website, I found the same notches on the exact same letters. And if you zoomed in on one of those letters, the notches stood out plain as day.
>   Halliday had put them there. He'd marked these letters for a reason.
>   There turned out to be one hundred and twelve of these notched letters scattered throughout the book. By writing them down in the order they appeared, I discovered they spelled something.
>
> <sub>*Ready Player One* by Ernest Cline, chapter "0006"</sub>

---

*Ready Player One* features notched letters as well.

> The first line of each chapter, except for chapter "0017", is written in a different font. The first lines of the chapters "0000" through "0006" have similar notches.

These letters spell out

> anoraksalmanacdotcom

In other words,

> the website [anoraksalmanac.com](http://anoraksalmanac.com)

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://www.reddit.com/r/readyplayerone/comments/2hlnii/finding_the_url_for_the_first_gate_in_the_book/) on reddit suggests that there wasn't a single page, it was a series of typos within the dead tree version of the book, **marked against the chapter headings**.

> *If you look in a physical copy of the book, you'll notice the first lines/words of each chapter are in a different font*