# What did the contest tied to Ready Player One entail?

Tags: ready-player-one

The book *Ready Player One* by Ernest Cline contains an [easter egg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/168816/19561). That easter egg points to the URL

> [anoraksalmanac.com](http://anoraksalmanac.com).

When going there, we can enter the First Gate.

[image: An image of a gate, with the text "Congratulations! You have found the First Gate."]

After going through the First Gate, we're informed that

> THIS CONTEST IS OFFICIALLY OVER!
>
> (Buy you can still play through the challanges [sic] for fun.)

**What did that contest entail?**

What were the challenges, what were the prizes, who won?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Courtesy of [this site](http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/scifi/ready-player-delorean-contest-winner-announced.html):

> The Ready Player One easter egg hunt was elaborate. Once readers found the URL hidden in the hardcover or paperback versions of Cline’s novel, the link took them to a new Atari 2600 video game called Stacks. After completing the First Gate, the winners would have to play a new Facebook video game created by legendary developer Richard Garriott de Cayeux. After completing the Second Gate, the third and final challenge was to set a new world record for either Pac-Man, Joust Arcade, Joust Atari 2600, Black Tiger, or Robotron 2084.

The winner was Craig Queen and his final prize was a vintage DeLorean awarded for setting a new world record for his score in *Joust Atari 2600* just eight days after the terms for the third gate were established.

Comment: Oh, is that all you had to do, set a new world record? Oh, if that’s all then- WHAT

Comment: VINTAGE DeLorean?! What kind of prize is this?! And World Record as the condition? This is contests amped up to 11...

Answer (score 6):

**Here is the contest in Craig Queen's, the winner's, own words:**

> “I found out about the contest on June 7 when I was checking out your blog. I took my lunch and found the clue in the book in 15 minutes. I had the first gate found, entered and cleared within 3 hours, if I remember right.
>
> The second gate took longer. I logged in with everyone else when it opened on July 1. Kept trying over the next 5 days until I had cleared it late on July 5. I just kept plugging away at it whenever I had a chance, despite my family teasing me about how crazy I was and how much of a geek I am. Like I quote: “I’ve been welcomed to the dark side; they had cookies!” My daughter would call it the ‘dork side.’
>
> Finally, the third gate opened August 1. Like everyone, I was floored by the challenge, but I felt it was on par with the book, so I didn’t get angry. Instead, I immediately started looking for locations that might carry the original arcade games and found one in Louisville that carried three of them: Robotron 2084, Joust, and Tempest. I contacted the owner and squared things away to take the challenge there. Then I found two more games had been added, so I changed my plans. I had just bought an Atari 2600 a month prior (thanks to your book, I got all nostalgic), but I did not have a copy of Joust. I logged into eBay quickly on August 1 and found a brand new, unopened copy for 13.95. I figured between all the gas I would have bought and the games I would have had to pump quarters into, it was a fair trade after doing the math.
>
> I purchased it and it arrived on August 4th at about 4 pm. I played a few games and kept getting my tail waxed for about 3 hours until I was able to break 160,000. I turned it off, told myself to step back and think about what I had played, and come back at it in the morning. The reflection was good because I recognized something in the game that would help me. I tried out two new techniques first thing in the morning on August 5 and was able to break 200,000 on my first play. I played once more and fell back below that mark. I chided myself for playing too long and promised I would only play one game at a time and then break for a few hours. That evening at 7 pm, I played another game (after working outside most of the afternoon) and made it to almost 900,000. I had quadrupled my score from the morning and knew I was ready to begin taping myself. My daughter Michelle got home at 9, and by 10 pm, we were ready and began taping. This game was just too perfect; everything was in place, and I had found my sweet spot (really felt like Wade Watts, LOL). My game lasted about 2 1/2 hours (about 45 minutes per million or so), and I finished at about 12:34 am on August 6th. I was tired from the day’s work outside, and my hands were killing me. I essentially just started letting my lives go after going ahead nearly 200,000. Altogether from the time I received the Joust cartridge till I beat the record was about 32 1/2 hours. I couldn’t believe I had done it: broke the record with 3,219,000 and was on wave 299 (I went back and looked), all under a day and a half!

Here is a picture of the winner with the new car:

[image]

Read more here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171024091450/ernestcline.com/blog/2012/09/02/the-grand-prize-delorean-at-its-new-home/